# Call server side method using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, excel

I am working on asp.net and i have the following c# method that exports grid views data to excel sheet, this method is been called through ImageButton click event:

```
public void GridToExcel()
{
    if (berthOccupancyDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BerthOccupancy.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        berthOccupancyDataGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        if (reportType == "Year To Date")
        {
            foreach(GridView gv in gridViewList)
            {
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            recapGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        }

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have List that stores dynamically created GridViews. The problem is The image button fires PostBack and sit this list to null. I tried many ways to prevent it from doing PostBack, such as using OnClienClick="return false;" but it didn't work.
I tried using ScriptManager and WebMethods, but it requires setting the method to static  and setting the method to static shows the following errors:

> **Error   2   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'**     
>   **Error   5   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BerthOccypancyForm.berthOccupancyDataGridView'**

Is there a way to call this method using AJAX without using WebMethods and PageMethods??

Appreciate your help..

Comment: you can use the WebAPI instead web methods in asp.net

Comment: Why can you not bind the grid on every PostBack?

Comment: you can do this, if instead of the gridview control you extract the data from the database

Comment: @CosmosBanda thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your suggestions. I was able to solve it this way.

I have added a static class that has static List and static string. And i call this Class in the WebForm. This way keep the data of GridViews during the PostBack

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
public static class Global
{

    public static List<GridView> GridViewList = new List<GridView>();
    public static string ReportType = "";
}
```

The following C# Function exports to excel using the data from the static Class.

```
public  void GridToExcel()
{
    if (berthOccupancyDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BerthOccupancy.xls");
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        berthOccupancyDataGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        if (Global.ReportType == "Year To Date")
        {
            foreach (GridView gv in Global.GridViewList)
            {
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
            }
        }
        else if(Global.ReportType == "Monthly")
        {
            recapGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        }

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by keeping the data of the list and the variables during the PostBack by using the following code:

**(The problem with this answer is that the session data is timeout by default after 20 mins. and sessions are not used to store big data such as gridviews)**

This one for preserving GridViewList data:

```
public List<GridView> Code
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] = new List<GridView>();
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] as List<GridView>;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] = value;
    }

}
```

This one for preserving the string data:

```
  public string RT
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["RT"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["RT"] = "" ;
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["RT"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["RT"] = value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26621/Cache-Session-and-ViewState.

Comment: @CosmosBanda Thank you for the article. I did a test and the session was timeout after 20 minutes the gridviews where not show in the excel sheet. Is it fine if i don't make session  timeout ? and then i remove it after exporting the file? Or you have a better solution?

Comment: why i posted a link, is because you are not supposed to use the session to store gridview information in it. Session is designed to store small pieces of information (like user ID, user email etc) throughout the lifecycle of the user session

Comment: @CosmosBanda Hmm. yeah i understand. So is the best way to call it using AJAX and that prevent it from loading the whole page? if it is, it seems i can't find a way to call this server function through client side function.

Comment: i am not sure if it is the best way, but i have a similar scenario to yours where i place the whole gridview in an update panel, then i have gridview buttons that export data to the client. So this way you avoid a full post back. So if you do use this method, one issue you are going to face is the response.write is not going to work and what you will have to do is register a full post back for the gridview button that does the export. I can provide you with my code if you wish

Comment: @CosmosBanda Yeah i tried to use ScriptManager which as AJAX process and it requires the methodto be static and i faced issue with response. Yes i would like to see your solution if you don't mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So i have a `gridview` control in an update panel, which basically provides a list of data to the user like this:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="transactionGrid" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped"
                                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                OnRowCommand="transactionGrid_RowCommand"
                                OnRowDataBound="transactionGrid_RowDataBound"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="transactionGrid_PageIndexChanging">
                                <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <a runat="server" href="~/PayrollManagement/Transaction/TransactionEntry.aspx" class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Add</a>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="cmdPrint" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-outline ttip btn-sm" ToolTip="Print Batch" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            CommandName="printBatch" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
                                            <span><i class=" fa fa-print fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="cmdExportCSV" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-outline ttip btn-sm" ToolTip="Export Batch" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            CommandName="exportBatch" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
                                            <span><i class=" fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="cmbEditBatch" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-outline ttip btn-sm" ToolTip="Edit Batch" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            CommandName="editBatch" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
                                            <span><i class=" fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="cmdPost" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-outline ttip btn-sm" ToolTip="Post Batch" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            CommandName="postBatch" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
                                            <span><i class=" fa fa-archive fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Batch ID" DataField="HEADERID" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Payroll Name" DataField="PAYROLLNAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Created" DataField="DATECREATED" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Created By" DataField="CREATEDBY" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Batch Date" DataField="BATCHDATE" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Farm Name" DataField="FARMNAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Batch Status" DataField="STATUSDESC" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Batch Desc" DataField="BATCHDESC" />
                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdSearch" EventName="click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdPostBatch" EventName="click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <div hidden="hidden">
    <iframe src="../CSVExport/ExportToCsv.aspx" runat="server" id="csvFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

Within the gridview as you can see there is an `exportBatch` link button which is assigned to every row. So when the user clicks the `exportBatch` button i run my code behind to compile the csv, in your case it will export to excel.

So this is the code behind for the `rowcommand method`:

```
        protected void transactionGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        int index;
        GridViewRow row;
        int batchID;

        processPayBatch dal = new processPayBatch();
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "exportBatch":
                index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                row = transactionGrid.Rows[index];
                batchID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);

                Session["csvbatch"] = batchID;
                csvFrame.Attributes["src"] = "/CSVExport/ExportToCsv.aspx";

                //Download the CSV file.


                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();", true);
                break;

        }

    }
```

So when the row button is clicked i submit a form in within an iframe. This is the code for the ExportToCsv page:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) {
            processPayBatch dal = new processPayBatch();
            int batchID = (int)Session["csvbatch"];
            Session["csvbatch"] = null;
            dal.ExportToCSV(batchID);

            string csv = dal.csvFile;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(csv);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Queries the database and retrieves the necessary information and compiles it into a csv file.

The reason why i chose to go with an iframe, was because the response.write was not running if i had to execute it in gridview code behind(because of the update panel).

Comment: thank you for your help. I have posted an answer that sows how i have solved it. I did it by creating a static class that has static List<GridView>. is used to store maintain data of gridviews during postback.